how do i solve this IDs is expected to be empty while trying to create and store embeding
I am getting the following error while trying to create and store embeding
File 
"C:\Users\Yusuf\miniconda3\envs\genai\lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\types.py",
line 228, in validate_ids
    raise ValueError(f"Expected IDs to be a non-empty list, got {len(ids)} IDs")
    ValueError: Expected IDs to be a non-empty list, got 0 IDs

chroma.persist()

This code is showing this error above :
chroma = Chroma(embedding_function=hf_embeddings, persist_directory=chroma_db_path)
chroma.add_texts(texts=split_texts, embeddings=embeddings, metadatas=[{'source': doc['source']} for doc in documents])
chroma.persist()

I tried to use this but I still get the same error:

Create unique IDs for each split text

ids = [f"doc_{i}" for i in range(len(split_texts))]  # Example: doc_0, doc_1, ...


How about including the ids when you add to the db
chroma.add_texts(
    texts=split_texts, 
    embeddings=embeddings, 
    metadatas=[{'source': doc['source']} for doc in documents], 
    ids=ids  # Include the IDs here
)

